# Bluez on Raspberry Pi: No such device

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi, bluez

I am actually trying to install and run Bluez on my raspberry pi. I am using Cambridge silicon Radio Bluetooth device. Everything is set but when I check my device using "hcitool dev", it is not showing my device. When search it is showing "No such device". "lsusb" detects my device and the bluetooth is running. Please help. I went through so many links but I couldn't find any solution for the problem.

Comment: Did you try 'hciconfig hci0 reset' or 'hciconfig hci0 up' ?

Comment: Yes. Getting errors for both. Getting error "Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out(110)".

Comment: Can you try these commands and see if they do anything for you: #service bluetooth start, or #/etc/init.d/bluetooth start, or #modprobe btusb or #modprobe ohci-hcd.

Comment: Thank everyone for this help. However the problem is solved. I just installed dbus and restarted. My bluetooth bongle was connected via USB Hub. I reconnected dongle directly into RPi port. Now it's working. Didn't do anything more. Problem is solved.